# Using tabs inside a Fragment (not FragmentActivity)

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I'm currently creating an app in which the main screen is build up out of 2 `Fragments`. 
When the user selects options on the main screen, one part of the screen gets replaced by a new `Fragment`, all pretty much basic stuff.

Now I'm trying to create a screen with several tabs, which all open a new fragment inside them. I had this working with regular intents, but that was before switching to `Fragments`.
I read that this is possible by using a `FragmentActivity`, but sadly you can't replace a `Fragment` with a `FragmentActivity`, simply because the transaction won't let you.

Is there any way of doing this inside an ordinary `Fragment`? Or should I try mimicking the behavior by using a layout with a fragment inside which gets replaced by another one at the press of a button, much like the main screen?  (Or won't that work due to fragments in fragments?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in Android's support library that describes what seems to be what you need. You can find it here: [`FragmentTabs`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html).

Comment: Yeah I've seen that one and even tried it myself, but it has exactly the problem I explained in my post. It uses FragmentActivity, so I can't use it to replace my main fragment, simply because the TransactionManager only takes Fragments and not FragmentActivities.
And the fact the XML files are missing from that example isn't really helping either since that leaves you with some errors and no clues on how to fix it.

Comment: So basically you need tabs that host activities?

Comment: No I need tabs that host fragments, inside a fragment. I'm not even sure if that's possible, hence why I asked.   I'm creating an app completely out of fragments (splits the interface in two, one part stays static) so I can't really use activities since those won't work within the layout as far as I know.

Comment: I actually tried it again just now, and remembered why it wouldn't work for me.
The example uses fragments with empty constructors to add to the tabs, but my fragments rely on their constructor to receive some data from another fragment when they are created. This data is used to call a webserver, and without this data the server simply can't be called thus leaving the fragment without content. When you try using a fragment that only has a non-empty constructor, you get an "unable to instantiate fragment" error, and a request for an empty constructor.

Comment: Overall, fragments cannot host other fragments directly. But I can think of one dirty way of achieving this functionality, though at expense of some resources and code beauty.

Comment: Fragments must always have default constructor! If you want to pass arguments, use `setArguments()`. Read more about this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Fragment%28%29

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid for. But I think if I resort back to regular activities just for the tabbed section of the app, it will take up the entire screen overlapping the static part of the app. That's something I'd rather try to avoid.  Would be idea of creating a layout that uses buttons instead of the tabs to mimic the behavior work? Otherwise I can always try that eventually.

Comment: @constructor  Oh wow how did I miss that one! Time to backtrack and add empty constructors everywhere. I'll give that and the `setArguments()` a try, it might just be what I'm looking for

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5671/discussion-between-inazaruk-and-sander-vant-veer)